# Visual Studio: Missing Ctrl+O+O, Ctrl+T Eclipse analog

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I very like Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> hotkey which includes in the list of members not only members of current class, but also all the members of all super-classes.
"Quick type hiererchy" feature also is pretty useful. Resharper has <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> keys, but it doesn't organize result in a tree what is very handy.

Is it possible to get mentioned functionality in VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReSharper provides the Type Hierarchy window (ReSharper > Inspect > Type Hierarchy) for investigating inheritance.

File Structure (ReSharper > Windows > File Structure) is ReSharper's version of Outline, and it could be what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can step on the name of a superclass or interface being implemented in the type declaration, invoke ReSharper > Navigate > Navigate to, and choose Implementing members - it will highlight you all members from the given interface that are implemented in the current class, and you can navigate between the highlights.

If you tell me more about your usage scenario, i.e. what task you're trying to solve with an analog of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, I could advise you how to solve this task with ReSharper.

UPDATE:

ReSharper 6 (pre-release builds of which can be found [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds)) provides a feature that corresponds to your usage scenario. In a file containing a class from an hierarchy, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (IntelliJ IDEA keymap) to invoke "Go to File Members". Then, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by Space to switch on the "Include members from related files" feature. This will show you any members in types up the inheritance hierarchy. You can flush results to the Find Results window by pressing <kbd>+</kbd>, and group them in a preferred way:
[image: Two ways of presenting related file members in ReSharper]

Comment: Resharper has "Enter member name:" quickfind window. The problem is that this windows doesn't include supertypes. And often I don't know where exactly in hiererchy the member is. So I need to include all supertypes to the "Enter member name:" quickfind window... I.e. Resharper has only analog of Ctrl+O, but doesn't have analog of Ctrl+O+O. Usage scenario is very simple. If class "B" extends "A", "A" contains field "a", and you need to go to "a" field from B window editor - you can't. Now imagine that D extends C extends B extends A and you don't know in which class the desired field is

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. ReSharper 6 that is currently in EAP (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds) has this feature. I'll update the answer with more details.