# What is Eclipse's Ctrl+O keyboard shortcut equivalent in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

**Question**

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio to show all methods of the class and to quickly jump to one by typing the first few letters of the method name and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

This is what <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> looks like in Eclipse.

[image]

Image source: http://rayfd.files.wordpress.com/2007/05/ctrl_o_2.jpg?w=700

**Side notes**

Without using ReSharper as described here [Visual Studio: Missing Ctrl+O+O, Ctrl+T Eclipse analog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670000/visual-studio-missing-ctrloo-ctrlt-eclipse-analog)

And something that is better than <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> as described in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394762/33311).

Answer (score 6):

You may use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> (go to symbol...) as alternative.

Comment: When I try this, I get the "open project" dialog.

Comment: Worked in VS Code. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you..This should have been the selected answer.

Comment: VS Code != Visual Studio

Comment: Does not work for Visual Studio 2012 which the question is about

Answer (score 4):

(I'm going to assume you're using the 'General Development' settings for keyboard shortcuts)

Without using any addins to achieve this and without using the method explained in the other SO answer about the only approaches I can think of are the following:

Use <kbd>Ctrl + ,</kbd> to bring up the `Navigate To...` window, however it searches across everything not just your current file.

Or.... you could do a little keyboard gymnastics, though it's nowhere near as simple as the Ctrl+O option from Eclipse or the other approaches that have been suggested.

If you scope Solution Explorer to the current file then you can just use the <kbd>Ctrl + ;</kbd> to search the methods and properties in the file.

To set the scope in Solution Explorer you can use <kbd>Ctrl + [</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> to sync SE with your current file. You could then map something like <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> to the ProjectAndSolutionContextMenus.Project.ScopeToThis command in Visual Studio's keyboard options. The only hassle with this approach is that you'll need to click the back button to go back to the full solution explorer view.

Alternatively if you use <kbd>Ctrl + [</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> you can toggle the **Open Files** filter in Solution Explorer's. Assuming you don't have too many open files then this might be a pretty simple way to do it.

Sorry to say, but your best option would be to use an add-in that provides a "go to member" function, such as [AsEclipse](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99ede732-544c-4f3b-8e38-49e4b8395075/) (I haven't tried it) or one of the other commercial productivity tools.  You might also drop a suggestion on the [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) site for it.

Answer (score -2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then type <kbd>@</kbd>

You'll get all the method names opened in that file, as a suggestion, and can jump from there itself.

**Edit:** this only works for VSCode.